# Create CIDR dynamically in AWS Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, subnet, cidr

Below is my AWS cloud formation template for creating VPC and subnets.The VPC is getting created successfully, but not the subnet's. I have tried giving my specific IP range , but it's failing with the error 'The CIDR '172.31.48.0/20' is invalid' How can i create the respective CIDRBlock dynamically in the template using JSON ?

```
"VPC1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.10.0.0/16",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "false",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "My Dashboard"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "subnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.48.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }          
    },
    "subnet2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "MyDashboard"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "subnet3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.32.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }
    }
```

The VPC is getting created successfully, but not the subnet's. I have tried giving my specific IP range , but it's failing with the error `'The CIDR '172.31.48.0/20' is invalid'` How can i create the respective CIDRBlock dynamically in the template using JSON ?

Answer (score 2):

Subnets should be in the same network as the vpc. Trying 10.10.1.0/24 , 10.10.2.0/24 and 10.10.3.0/24 worked for subnets.

got the answer here : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=756147#756147